# Extract Language of HTML document XPath

Tags: html, xpath

I am new to XPath. I am trying to extract the Language (content of `lang` attribute in the `<html>` tag) of an HTML document like this https://policies.google.com/privacy/archive?hl=de. I have tried out this here:

```
//html[@lang]
```

but this doesn't give me "de" Text of the document language. Can someone help me please? I have tested the above query with ChroPath.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath,

```
//html[@lang]
```

selects all `html` elements in the document that have a `@lang` attribute.

This XPath,

```
/html/@lang
```

selects the `@lang` attribute of the `html` root element.

Comment: I have tried this, too (sorry forgotten to mention) but the same issue :(.
EDIT: I have tested it in RapidMiner where I want to use this query and it works, but I don't know why ChroPath don't gives me the same result. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mike, technically `/html/@lang` selects an attribute node and not the string value `de` so depending on how you use XPath or your environment or API exposes the result of an XPath evaluation you might need more steps, either in XPath or in the API, for instance in pure XPath you can use the expression `string(/html/@lang)` to get the string value of the `lang` attribute or in client-side Javascript or in Google Chrome's console where `$x('/html/@lang')` gives you an array with the attribute node you would need  `$x('/html/@lang')[0].nodeValue` to get that string value.

Comment: @Mike, I don't know ChroPath however, so you will need to check whether the advice in the previous comment applies.

Comment: Thank you Martin for the advice. ChroPath is the XPath extension for Google Chrome to check via Chrome your queries.